# working with populate and findById in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have three different Models: Product, Shop, and User
What I am trying to accomplish is to populate getProduct route with Shop and User.

```
router.route('/:productId').get(productController.getProduct);
```

**Product Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'Name is required']
  },
  image: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  category: {
    type: String
  },
  quantity: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
    required: [true, 'Quantity is required']
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'Price is required']
  },
  updated: Date,
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  shop: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Shop' },
  owner: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }]
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

**User Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'Name is required']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter a valid email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email']
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user',
    enum: ['owner', 'seller', 'user', 'admin']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false
  },
  seller: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  updated: Date,
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    select: false
  },
  created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});
```

Product Controller

```
exports.getProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  Product.findById(req.params.productId)
    .populate('shop', 'name _id')
    .populate('owner', 'name _id')
    .exec((err, product) => {
      if (err || !product)
        return res.status('400').json({
          error: 'Product not found'
        });
      res.status(200).json(product);
    });
};
```

**User controller**

```
exports.getUser = asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.userId);

  if (!user) {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('No user found!', 404));
  }

  res.status(200).json({ user });
});
```

However, the shop populate is working fine, the thing that I can not figure it out why owner is not populating.

**this is *getProduct* route in postman**

```
{    
    "image": {...
    },
    "quantity": 6,
    "owner": [],
    "_id": "5e67a428f7927504e87d30de",
    "name": "calculator",
    "description": "a calculator for senior students",
    "category": "school",
    "price": 150,
    "created": "2020-03-10T14:28:56.214Z",
    "shop": {
        "_id": "5e5e0eb64a6a2d0766eda2cb",
        "name": "a basket"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Does that Product document really has the owner array with object ids that exists in the User collection?

Comment: I edit the question and add the user model.

Comment: Can you add the Product document and the corresponding User documents?

Comment: Do we need to add Product as a ref to User Model as well?

Comment: Not necessary. But your product document’s owmer array must have ids of users, like [“userid1”, ”userid2”]